# Can "v17 leanback library"(android tv support library) support 2.x or 4.x device?

Tags: android, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop, television

I have some trouble when develop on TV device, Can "v17 leanback library" support 2.x or 4.x device?

"v17 leanback library" is a TV Support Libraries.It request the app's minSdkVersion is "android-L",so app can't run on 2.x or 4.x device.Do you have some suggest?

you can visit [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/preview/tv/start/index.html) for more infomation.

Comment: the leanback library is a preview only, and so the API level is set at android-L to ensure you can't publish any apps using it to the App store yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be quite an old question and since the Lollipop announcement, I guess it's easy to say that yes, since the Leanback API has been integrated in a support library.

`compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:21.0.0'`

I actually had some fun implementing the samples and my custom apps using it on Android KitKat and it all works like a charm.

Interesting to say though, you won't have the nice transitions as you can see them on Lollipop.

**Edit**: *It is important to know that the leanback library supports all API levels starting from 17. However, you won't have all transitions and the BackgroundManager will not work prior to API 21.*

Comment: only support at api17 device and above

Comment: @RahulMatte you can git leanback lib code by https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support

Comment: @张文枫 What's difference between your code and https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback apart from Eclipse and Android Studio Environment respectively

Comment: @RahulMatte you can change the code for custom function and style

Comment: is the presenter widget working fine on you? My presenter widget become messy in API 19 and fewer