# Run my AndroidTV application in android 4.x

Tags: android, android-tv

Based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438755/can-v17-leanback-libraryandroid-tv-support-library-support-2-x-or-4-x-device), it seems it's possible to run Leanback library on 4.2 and above. But it's not working well when I generated the project by default Android Studio TV template.

Here is the result:

In 5.0:

[image]

In 4.4:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: In accordance to Google [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html), you must build the TV app using Android SDK 5.0 (API 21) or higher. Why would you want to use an older SDK, which is not supported?

Comment: I also have the same problem. I found an app in Android Kitkat that is using leanback (browsefragment) but works well. there must be an explanation for that

Answer (score 0):

The Leanback support library supports versions v17 and up from an API perspective, although it was designed for Android TV, which is for Lollipop (v21) and up.

Is there a specific reason you're trying to run Leanback in 4.4?

Comment: Because I have an Android application which is running in some Android SmartTV. The version of android in those SmartTV is before 21, for example, 4.4, I'd like to support them too.